# String value not changing

Tags: c#, string, timer, serial-communication

Hi, I have code that reads and writes to a COM port. When the program reads from the COM port it searches for a string value and puts it in a variable. After it does this, it again listens to the COM port. I need to write to the COM port and read some new data, but I'm not seeing the value has changing to a new value.

Here is my code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sq = "777";
        if (CommunicationManager.myQ.Count != 0)
        {
            sq = CommunicationManager.myQ.Dequeue().ToString();
            textBox1.Text = sq + textBox1.Text;
            buffer = Regex.Match(textBox1.Text, @"\
                         ((.+?)\,15,").Groups[1].Value;
        }
    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        for (int i = 0; i <= numtst; i++)
        {
            listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.White;
            fl[i] = false;
        }

        nt = 0;
        flon = false;
        flag[0] = false;

            comm.WriteData("AT\r\n");
            wait(700);
            if (buffer.lenght == 16)
            { 
               flag[0] = true
            }
            if (flag[0] == true)
            {
                flon = true;
                CommunicationManager.myQ.Clear();
                break;
            }
        }            
        if (flon == true)
        {
            listView1.Items[nt].BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            fl[nt] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            listView1.Items[nt].BackColor = Color.Red;
            if (flag[76] == true)
            {

                button1.Enabled = true;
                button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                button1.Text = "Test ERROR";                  
                return;
            }
        }
        comm.WriteData("ATT\r\n");
        wait(3700);
        comm.WriteData("AT4\r\n");

        nt = 1;
        flon = false;
        flag[1] = false;

           if (buffer == text4.text)
           {
              flag[1] = true
           }
            wait(700);
            if (flag[1] == true)
            {
                flon = true;
                CommunicationManager.myQ.Clear();
                break;
            }
            if (flag[76] == true)
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        if (flon == true)
        {
            listView1.Items[nt].BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            fl[nt] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            listView1.Items[nt].BackColor = Color.Red;
            if (flag[76] == true)
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                button1.Text = "Test ERROR";
                return;
            }
        }
```

in the second part  if `(buffer == text4.text)` i see only first value of the buffer variable.

i checked in the terminal and all commands working good.

Comment: Can you explain and isolate the actual issue? It's a bit unclear where exactly your problem occurs.

Comment: you should probably show how the buffer class is defined. is buffer.text a String class? for instance, the == operator can sometimes compare object pointers, and not the content of the object.

Comment: buffer is assigned to a value of type string in `timer1_Tick`. In `button1_Click`, buffer is used with `buffer.text`. IS that the same buffer variable? What is it's type?

Comment: CodeCaster i'm running app and checking the comport with the timer_tick, the program with the first function checking the queue from the comport and finding a string after this program do some another writes to the port and waiting for answers from the comport but second function see only first value from the timer_tick.

Comment: helb  it the same variable buffer in timer_tick and in button1_click